# C#: Read a text file into a 2D char array

Tags: c#, arrays, file, char, 2d

Like I mentioned above, I try to read a text file into a 2D char array.
That's my file:

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxy
```

and that's my code:

```
var path = @"C:text.file";
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path);
        {



            char[,] arr = new char[5, 5];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
              {
                  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                  {
                    arr[i, j] = (Char)sr.Read();
                   Console.WriteLine(arr[i, j] + " = {0},{1}", i,j);
                  }
              }

            Console.WriteLine(arr[2,1]);
        }
    }
```

and at least my output:

```
1 = 0,0
2 = 0,1
3 = 0,2
4 = 0,3
5 = 0,4
 = 1,0

 = 1,1
6 = 1,2
7 = 1,3
8 = 1,4
9 = 2,0
0 = 2,1
 = 2,2
...
```

so my question is, why e.g. arr[1,0] or arr[1,1] is empty?

thanks for your help!
sno0z3

Comment: Probably because StreamReader.Read reads also the two newline characters at the end of each line. (ie \r\n)

Comment: that makes sense, do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: How are you parsing an integer "int x = Int32.Parse(sr.ReadLine());" when you have an input "fghij".

Comment: Read a line as a whole with ReadLine then use the ToCharArray string method

Comment: As @jdweng noted that cannot be your input file because the first Int.Parse will throw with that inputs and is not clear how do you get a 1 from the first char on each line here.

Comment: Ah just ignore that, it was from a previous version

Comment: @Steve but that doesn't work with a 2D array

Comment: The information you provide must be accurate in order for us to be able to evaluate the issue. Providing erroneous "input" values is misleading and frustrating. 'Just ignore that' is not the proper response. The proper response would be to provide valid data. [mcve]

Comment: @Barns sorry you are right, I already edited the code

Comment: @sno0z3 why not? Once you have your line in memory it is just an array of 5 letters and you can loop over that array and assign the char one by one to the i,y entries

Comment: @Steve It tells me that I cannot convert a "char" in type char[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the presence of a newline at the end of each line (and a newline is composed of two characters in a Windows text file).
So you can check for these characters before adding to your array, or simply read the line (thus removing the newline) and then loop over the string obtained extracting char by char and adding them to your array

```
char[,] arr = new char[5, 5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   string curLine = sr.ReadLine();
   for (int j = 0; j < curLine.Length; j++)
   {
      arr[i, j] = curLine[j];
      Console.WriteLine(arr[i, j] + " = {0},{1}", i,j);
   }
}
```

Comment: stupid question... when I create my test file in Linux I wouldn't have the problem?

Comment: In Linux the newline is just one char, but ReadLine takes care of removing the undesidered chars

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution has no checks against unexpected condiftions, like a line too long for your 5 array entries or a file with less than 5 lines.